# cannot edit the images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have created a very simple admin panel, where the admin could create edit and destroy articles.

**Edit** doesn't work as expected... I can edit the text as I want, but the pictures remain the same...even if I change...
How can I fix this?
thanks for your help!

```
  class Admin::ProgressesController < Admin::ApplicationController

    if Rails.env.production?
      http_basic_authenticate_with :name => ENV["ADMIN_NAME"],:password => ENV["ADMIN_PASSWORD"]
    else
      http_basic_authenticate_with :name => "admin", :password => "password"
    end

    def index
      @progresses = Progress.all
    end

    def new
      @progress = Progress.new
    end

    def show
      @progress = Progress.find(params[:id])

    end

    def create
       @progress = Progress.new(progress_params)

       respond_to do |format|
         if @progress.save
           unless params[:progress_attachments].nil?
             params[:progress_attachments]['image'].each do |a|
               @progress_attachment = @progress.progress_attachments.create!(:image => a)
             end
           end
           format.html { redirect_to admin_progresses_path, notice: 'Progress was successfully created.' }
         else
           format.html { render action: 'new' }
         end
       end

     end

     def edit
       @progress = Progress.find(params[:id])
     end

     def destroy
        @progress = Progress.find(params[:id])
        @progress.destroy
        flash[:success] = "Article was successfully deleted"
        redirect_to admin_progresses_path
     end

#EDIT: Added the  `puts ("params________")+params.to_json`
    def update
      puts ("params________")+params.to_json
      @progress = Progress.find(params[:id])
        if @progress.update(params[:progress].permit(:title, :content, :date, :main_image, progress_attachments_attributes: [:id, :progress_id, :image] ))
          flash[:success] = "Article was successfully updated"
          redirect_to admin_progresses_path

        else
      render 'edit'
        end
        end

     private

     def progress_params
        params.require(:progress).permit(:title, :content, :date, :main_image, progress_attachments_attributes: [:id, :progress_id, :image])
     end

  end
```

this is my index.html.slim

```
.container
  .row
    h1 Pepito's Dashboard
    br
    = link_to "New article", new_admin_progress_path, class:'btn btn-success'
    br
    br

    table.board
      thead
        tr
          th
            .table-title Title
          th
            .table-date Date
          th
            .table-content Content
          th
            .table-actions Actions
    tbody
    hr.bold-line
      .dashboard
        - @progresses.each do |progress|
          .row 
            .col-xs-2
              h4
              = progress.title.capitalize
            .col-xs-2
              h4
              = progress.date
            .col-xs-5
              h4  
              = truncate(progress.content, length: 90)
            .col-xs-1
              = link_to 'View', progress_path(progress), class:'btn btn-success'
            .col-xs-1
              = link_to 'Edit', edit_admin_progress_path(progress), class:'btn btn-primary'
            .col-xs-1
              = link_to 'Destroy', admin_progress_path(progress), class:'btn btn-danger', method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure Pepito?"}
          hr
```

Thanks for your help :)

## EDIT 1

this is my model

```
class Progress < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope ->{order(created_at: :DESC)}
  has_many :progress_attachments
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :progress_attachments, :allow_destroy => true
  mount_uploader :main_image, ImageUploader
  validates :main_image,   presence: true
  validates :title,   presence: true
  validates :content,  presence: true
  validates :date,    presence: true

end
```

## EDIT 2

```
class ProgressAttachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
  belongs_to :progress
  validates :image, presence: true  
end
```

Comment: What's the relationship between progress model and images (or attachment) model? Did you use  `accepts_nested_attributes_for :child` in the progress model?

Comment: yes I did, check my edit please :)

Comment: Check if in the update method you are receiving the correct params. Add `puts ("params________")+params.to_json`in the first line of the method and try to edit and update some record, check for the progress_attachments. Also can you show the  progress_attachments attachment model? Maybe there are some validation there that requiere another field or something.

Comment: The `main_image`change but the images from progress_attachements remain the same... :(

Comment: Then probably your problem is in the Edit view. If you are using the form helper make sure you are doing it right, check the fields_for attribute. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for . Here is an example https://www.sitepoint.com/complex-rails-forms-with-nested-attributes/

Answer (score 0):

You need to accept nested attributes for `progress_attachments` in your `progress` model.

```
class Progress
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :progress_attachments
end
```

Refer [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for)